# Can I put a wallpaper close to a light fixture?

Tags: bathroom, light-fixture, wallpaper

I didn't find any information about it and I'm wondering if I can have a wallpaper close to a light fixture like the image below:

The reason I'm asking is because we recently added both the wallpaper and the light fixture. After it was on for a while we could smell something weird... There were no smoke or anything. But a smell. I think it could be just the head on the glue, but then I decided to verify if it's ok to have wallpaper close to a light fixture as I didn't think about it before.

[image]

Comment: The light fixture would have been tested to insure that with the listed bulbs in place the glass globes are not so hot as to ignite nearby combustible materials on the wall. What kind of bulbs are you using? Perhaps one or more of the bulbs was coated with some sort of contaminant that volatilized. Is the odor persisting? Alternatively there may be a poor electrical connection which is arcing. If you listen, can you heat the "sizzling" sound of arcing?

Comment: I have seen wallpaper scorched by bulbs that are too hot for fixture. Make sure the bulbs are not of higher wattage than the max listed for that fixture. Switch to LED bulbs for cooler temps

Comment: It~s a G9 bulb, 60W. And we can't hear anything. After we turned off the odor was gone